# git checkout with commit ID?

Tags: git

I'm a git newbie, I've cloned the repository and I've been given a git commit ID.  When I try to do:

```
$ git checkout 2ae0568
```

I get:

```
error: pathspec '2ae0568' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

What haven't I done?

Comment: Either the commit id is incorrect or you need to specify more character for git to identify it

Comment: The problem was caused by being given the wrong information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given the wrong commit ID, for some reason even though I was specific in the repository I was working on the commit ID I was given was for another repository.

Several times I queried this and several times I was told, it works!

Now its cleared up, there is no longer an issue.  I would have deleted this but since there is already an answer I couldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Check if the commit exists first using:

```
$ git show <commit_id>
$ git checkout <commit_id>
```

Another way would be too:

```
$ git log --oneline | grep <commit_id>
```

If it exists then you can checkout to it. If you got that ID from remote branch, gitlab, github, make sure you have that branch locally as well.

Comment: When I do git show I get: fatal: ambiguous argument '2ae0568': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.  And git log --oneline | grep 2ae0568 returns nothing.

Comment: Where did you get the <commit_id> from? Maybe it doesn't exist?

Comment: Another developer, the developer of the package...

Comment: I think you've only cloned the master branch, or the branch on which the commit exists doesn't exist locally, make sure your branch is upto-date with master. May I ask, which branch does the commit belong to? And whether or not you have that particular branch locally?

Comment: You could be right, how do I clone it all?

Comment: Try using `$ git fetch `

Comment: Just done that...then git log again, still nothing

Comment: Maybe it has not been pushed, verify with the developer the branch, then locally check that branch, there is no circumstance in which git would behave like this, unless the commit was squashed, or deleted from the history while rebasing.

Comment: thank you, trying to get that verified

Comment: Let us know the updates as well.

Comment: @SPlatten cloning (without any flags) does get all the commits at the time of cloning.